# route:<nolink> looses styling and not working correctly in Superfish menu

Tags: navigation

I have set the parent item (reaching-out) on my main superfish menu as a "no link" item so that only the dropdown menu items link to pages. On doing so I lose my styling which is OK because somehow I manage to locate that specific menu item to style and match the others.
On hover the select icon replaces the arrow which is no big deal but it should not be so.
I notice the accordion menu needs separate styling - again I have managed to do this but very laborious. 
I could live with all this but I notice in the accordion position for mobiles the "reaching-out" link now doesn't expand to show the sub-1 menus on hover or press.

***I am wondering is there a better way than altering the no link on the Drupal menu system (ie via admin/structure/menu) which Superfish doesn't seem to be picking up correctly? Perhaps there are some superfish settings I have failed to pick up on which need no additional styling and function correctly.***
(In the pics I have removed the styling to show original problems. Its difficult to get a snip of an expanded menu in full screen view because you need to be on hover and cant click snip at the same time!)

[image: Accordion menu - "reaching out" being set to no link does not expand to reveal sub menus]

[image: Main menu loses styling]

[image: showing no link setting in admin - is there a better way in the superfish settings?]

Comment: I’m guessing it’s becahse the style expects an anchor tag, and there isn’t one for nolink.

Comment: Hi Kevin - Indeed I have managed to steer round all the styling using li:nth-child etc. My main concern is (and it isn't clear from the pics) that the link "reaching out" on the accordion menu for mobiles does not expand at all. I'm not very advanced when it comes to coding, patches etc but thought superfish would be foolproof when it comes to no linking on main menu items which must be common for drop downs...